# Finding corresponding elements in a string

Tags: java

Please refer tho this [question from hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=stacks-queues):

> A bracket is considered to be any one of the following characters: (,
>   ), {, }, [, or ].
>
> Two brackets are considered to be a matched pair if the an opening
>   bracket (i.e., (, [, or {) occurs to the left of a closing bracket
>   (i.e., ), ], or }) of the exact same type. There are three types of
>   matched pairs of brackets: [], {}, and ().
>
> A matching pair of brackets is not balanced if the set of brackets it
>   encloses are not matched. For example, {[(])} is not balanced because
>   the contents in between { and } are not balanced. The pair of square
>   brackets encloses a single, unbalanced opening bracket, (, and the
>   pair of parentheses encloses a single, unbalanced closing square
>   bracket, ]...

I have done the program as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static char findCorrBracket(char b)
    {
        if(b == '{')
        {
            return '}';
        }
        else if(b == '[')
        {
            return ']';
        }
        else 
        {
            return ')';
        }
    }

    // Complete the isBalanced function below.
    static String isBalanced(String s) {

        char a[] = new char[1000];
        int top = 0,i=1;
        a[0]=s.charAt(0);
        char retBrack;
        String result;


        while(top!=-1 )
        {
            retBrack=findCorrBracket(s.charAt(top));
            if(s.charAt(i)!=retBrack)
            {
                a[top]=s.charAt(i);
                top=i;
            }
            else
            {
                top--;
            }

            i++;
            if(i>=s.length()-1)
            {
                break;
            }

        }


        System.out.println(top);

        if(top==0)
        {
            result = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "NO";
        }



        return result;

    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getenv("OUTPUT_PATH")));

        int t = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        for (int tItr = 0; tItr < t; tItr++) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();

            String result = isBalanced(s);

            bufferedWriter.write(result);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
        }

        bufferedWriter.close();

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

I have changed the code a little bit. It has made the program more readable. But still, the problem persists.

```
/******************************************************************************

                            Online Java Debugger.
                Code, Run and Debug Java program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Debug" button to debug program.

*******************************************************************************/

public class Main
{


    static char findCorrBracket(char b)
    {
        if(b == '{')
        {
            return '}';
        }
        else if(b == '[')
        {
            return ']';
        }
        else 
        {
            return ')';
        }
    }

    // Complete the isBalanced function below.
    static String isBalanced(String s) {

        char a[] = new char[1000];
        int top = 0,i=1;
        a[0]=s.charAt(0);
        char retBrack;
        String result;

        while(i<s.length())
        {
            retBrack=findCorrBracket(s.charAt(top));
            if(s.charAt(i)!=retBrack)
            {
                top++;
                a[top]=s.charAt(i);


            }
            else
            {
                top--;
            }

            i++;

        }

        System.out.println(top);

        if(top==-1)
        {
            result = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "NO";
        }



        return result;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s="{[]()}";
        String result = isBalanced(s);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

It runs for few of the test cases, while for others it doesn't. How should I change the code?

Comment: `top=i;` should be `top++;`.   Also, I would strongly recommend replacing the `while` with something like `for (int i=1; i < s.length() && top >=0; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - I've added the corrections I made as comments in the code.

```
    static char findCorrBracket(char b)
    {
        if(b == '{')
        {
            return '}';
        }
        else if(b == '[')
        {
            return ']';
        } 
        else if(b == '(')
        {
            //Use else if here instead of else, since otherwise '}',']','(' & ')' will all get the returned character value ')'
            return ')';
        } else {
            return '_';
        }
    }

    // Complete the isBalanced function below.
    static String isBalanced(String s) {

        char a[] = new char[1000];
        int top = 0,i=1;
        a[0]=s.charAt(0);
        char retBrack;
        String result;

        while(i<s.length())
        {
            if(top == -1) {
                //If the stack is empty, then we don't need to get the 'correct bracket' and check
                //We can directly insert the character into the stack
                top++;
                a[top] = s.charAt(i);
            } else {
                //findCorrBracket from `a[top]`, not from `s.charAt(top)`
                retBrack = findCorrBracket(a[top]);
                if (s.charAt(i) != retBrack) {
                    top++;
                    a[top] = s.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    top--;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(top);
        if(top==-1)
        {
            result = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "NO";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

---

You loop should iterate through all the characters of the string. So, `while (i<s.length())` should be moved from inside the while block to the condition.

The `top` value needs to be incremented, not set to the value of `i`.

```
    // Complete the isBalanced function below.
    static String isBalanced(String s) {

        char a[] = new char[1000];
        int top = 0,i=1;
        a[0]=s.charAt(0);
        char retBrack;
        String result;


        while(i<s.length() )
        {
            retBrack=findCorrBracket(s.charAt(top));
            if(s.charAt(i)!=retBrack)
            {
                top++;
                a[top]=s.charAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                top--;
            }

            i++;
        }


        System.out.println(top);

        if(top==-1)
        {
            result = "YES";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "NO";
        }

        return result;
    }
```

P.S - There are a few improvements I could suggest,

1. As racraman suggested, use `for` loops instead of `while`, unless you need a `do while`.
2. Don't create a static array to use as a stack, use a Java collection (eg, `ArrayList`) to create a dynamic stack. This way, even if the string has more than a 1000 consecutive `(`, your code would work.

Comment: It is not working sir. Actually, the problem with my code is that I have written the code considering cases like: "{{([])}}","{[()]}" and not "{(([])[])[]}[]"

Comment: Just call me Jem, I'll take a look at the code again, I might have missed something.

Comment: Check if `top == - 1`, not `top==0`.

Comment: Hello Jem, would you mind checking my updated code. I feel that something is wrong with the increment and decrement of the variable top.

Comment: @Soumee Hi, I've updated my answer. I fixed my code and checked if it works in Hackerrank.

Comment: Do upvote and mark the answer as correct if it works. Feel free to comment if you have any more doubts, Cheers.

Comment: I ran your code in hackerrank. It runs for most of the cases excluding one. It is a significant improvement to my code. If you get some free time please check for the 9th case why it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196773/discussion-between-chrisvin-jem-and-soumee).

Comment: Hi, did you try directly copy pasting my code in hackkerank? I just rechecked, and the code runs for all the test cases for me.

Comment: I just rechecked. The findCorrBracket(char b) function also needs to be changed. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've started off on the right path, using a stack and iterating over the string one character at a time.  But your logic for each character doesn't seem to make any sense.  Apparently it "works" if the input string meets some *very* specific conditions, but not in general.  Something more like this (in pseudo-code) will work on *any* input:

```
for each character `c` in string `s`:
   if `c` is an opening bracket:
      PUSH`c` onto stack
   else: 
      // `c` must be a closing bracket
      if stack is EMPTY:
          's` IS UNBALANCED
      else:
          POP top of stack into `b`
          if `b` is not the correct matching opening bracket for `c`:
              `s` IS UNBALANCED
          end if
      end if
  end if
end for
if stack is EMPTY:
    SUCCESS! (`s` is correctly balanced)
else:
    `s` IS UNBALANCED
end if
```

Comment: Hello Kevin. Greetings! Would you mind checking my updated code. I feel that something is wrong with the increment and decrement of the variable top.